# How can i print a pdf in google chrome?

Tags: javascript

I have a pdf associated with a button . When i click the button i want to get the pdf printed. This is how my button is coded :

```
<input type="submit" class="btn-red" value="Print"
name="Submit" id="printbtn"
onclick="printPDF('http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf')" />
```

Now my print functionality works like this :

```
    function printPDF(pdfUrl)
    {

    if ((navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') ) 
    window.print(pdfUrl,"_self");
    else
    {
    var w = window.open(pdfUrl,"_self");
    w.print();
    w.close();
    }
    }
```

The problem is , it's working fine in IE and Fire fox , but does not work in chrome. In ie and Firefox, it opens up the xps printer option, but in chrome , it just opens up  a new print window, with the print preview of the div and not the pdf . But i want the xps option to be opened up here.

**EDIT :** In chrome when i try to print , only the html element comes as preview and not the pdf. I am using chrome version : 20.0.1132.57

How can i get around this peculiarity ? kindly help .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to do the same thing and I used a different approach, one that for me worked in both Chrome and Firefox.

My solution involved a print.html helper file, that received the PDF file's url as a GET type parameter, then loaded the pdf inside an iframe. Then it kept checking to see if the pdf had completely loaded (binding the check to the `onload` event did not work) and on completion it triggered the print method.

Here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <title>Print Page</title>

    <meta name="title" content="Print" /> 

    <script>

    (function (window, document, undefined) {


        var printy = {

                urlGET: function (param) {

                    var params = document.URL.split('?');

                    if(params.length > 1) {
                        params = params[1].split('&');

                        for (var  i = 0, len = params.length; i < len; i++) {
                            if (params[i].split('=')[0] === param) {
                                return params[i].split('=')[1];
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    return null;
                },


                init: function () {

                    var self = this;

                    window.onload = function () {

                        var src = self.urlGET('path');

                        //creating an iframe element
                        var ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
                        document.body.appendChild(ifr);

                        // making the iframe fill the viewport
                        ifr.width  = '100%';
                        ifr.height = window.innerHeight;

                        // continuously checking to see if the pdf file has been loaded
                        self.interval = setInterval(function () {

                            if (ifr.contentDocument.readyState === 'complete') {
                                clearInterval(self.interval);
                                // doing the actual printing
                                ifr.contentWindow.print();
                            }
                        }, 100); 

                        ifr.src = src;
                    }
                }
            }

            printy.init();

    })(window, document, undefined);
    </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This solution is not tested on IE though. We use Macs at work so it was not an option.

In order to do the printing, I use it by calling an URL like this: `http://example.com/print.html?path=docs/myfile.pdf`

Comment: Thanks for sharing it. Will check it out and let you know, whether it works for me.

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me and didn't require a host HTML file. The key was to wait for onload:

For a link like this:

```
<a class="print-pdf-link" href="/your/pdf.pdf">Print PDF</a>
```

I used javascript:

```
$('a.print-pdf-link').click(function () {
    var w = window.open($(this).attr('href'));

    w.onload = function () {
        w.print();
    };

    return false;
});
```